# (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)-error when starting dired

Tags: dired, debugging

Dired used to run fine on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04). But for a while now, i keep running into the error `(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)`. This does not only happen with *dired* but also with other commands taking an argument (from the minibar).

From searching the web it seems that the error message comes up in situations with some misconfiguration, but I haven't been able to figure it out just yet.

**Full error message:**

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
call-process(nil nil nil nil "--dired")
dired-insert-directory("/home/hb/test/" "-al" nil nil t)
dired-readin-insert()
dired-readin()
dired-internal-noselect("~/test/" nil)
dired-noselect("/home/hb/test/ nil)
dired("/home/hb/test/")
ido-file-internal(dired dired nil "Dired: " dir)
ido-dired()
call-interactively(ido-dired nil nil)
command-execute(ido-dired)
```

Comment: What's the value of `insert-directory-program`?

Comment: What @npostavs said. Also, does the same thing happen if you don't use Ido and just do `M-x dired`? What are the values of variables `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program` and `dired-use-ls-dired`? (The backtrace and the fact that the 3rd arg to `call-process` is `nil` suggests that this is happening directly in `dired-insert-directory` and not in `insert-directory`.) And what happens if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) - same problem?

Comment: @npostavs 'insert-directory-program is a variable defined in `files.el'. Its value is nil'
@Drew dired works without the init file. 'dired-use-ls-dired' is a variable defined in dired.el. 'Its value is unspecified'. 'ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program' doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: Something in your init file must be setting `insert-directory-program` to `nil`, the default value is `"ls"`.

Comment: well, I built upon the start-kit for social sciences and as this tailored to OSX the `inser-directory-program` was set to gls (GNU ls) which I didn't have on my machine. Commenting the part out solved the problem. Do you care to post it as an answer so that I can accept? Ty!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backtrace you give in the question actually has all the information you need to debug this so while the answer is in the comments I'll go through the logic.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
call-process(nil nil nil nil "--dired")
```

So an argument here has failed the *stringp* predicate check. This first place to look is at C-h f *call-process*:

```
call-process is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(call-process PROGRAM &optional INFILE DESTINATION DISPLAY &rest ARGS)

Call PROGRAM synchronously in separate process.
```

Well that's a bit of a pain, it is in the C code. If you have a copy of the code checked out you could have looked and found the following in *src/callproc.c*:

```
if (nargs >= 2 && ! NILP (args[1]))
  {
    infile = Fexpand_file_name (args[1], BVAR (current_buffer, directory));
    CHECK_STRING (infile);
  }
```

But as most people don't have the C code on their systems we'll look higher up the stack. From the help text though it seems pretty likely calling *call-process* with nil for its only mandatory argument isn't going to end well. So up the stack:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
call-process(nil nil nil nil "--dired")
dired-insert-directory("/home/hb/test/" "-al" nil nil t)
```

So we visit C-h f *dired-insert-directory* and follow the link to dired.el to look at the code. M-x narrow-to-defun and we can search just in this function for the *call-process* invocation:

```
(if (and
 ;; Don't try to invoke `ls' if we are on DOS/Windows where
 ;; ls-lisp emulation is used, except if they want to use `ls'
 ;; as indicated by `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program'.
 (not (and (featurep 'ls-lisp)
       (null ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program)))
 (or (if (eq dired-use-ls-dired 'unspecified)
     ;; Check whether "ls --dired" gives exit code 0, and
     ;; save the answer in `dired-use-ls-dired'.
     (or (setq dired-use-ls-dired
           (eq 0 (call-process insert-directory-program
                     nil nil nil "--dired")))
         (progn
           (message "ls does not support --dired; see `dired-use-ls-dired' for more details.")
           nil))
       dired-use-ls-dired)
     (file-remote-p dir)))
(setq switches (concat "--dired " switches)))
```

And we see the invocation:

```
(call-process insert-directory-program nil nil nil "--dired")
```

A quick C-h v *insert-directory-program*:

```
insert-directory-program is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.
Its value is "ls"

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Absolute or relative name of the ‘ls’ program used by ‘insert-directory’.
```

And if we follow the link to the definition:

```
(defvar insert-directory-program (purecopy "ls")
  "Absolute or relative name of the `ls' program used by `insert-directory'.")
```

So we can see it defaults to "ls", ergo if it is not set something has messed with the setting. You can verify this by running emacs -Q to confirm the default setup works.

Comment: this is awesome!

Comment: @stats-hb: given how much of Emacs' internals are directly accessible to the user I tend to prefer the "teach a man to fish" approach. Having said that it took me a long time to get used to the syntax - but once over that hurdle....